# app showing errors,cant fix

Tags: android

I am doing an android app. It was working fine.I could run it on Tuesday. When yesterday I open it is giving following error.

```
  Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
/SplashScreen/gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.   SplashScreen        line 1  Android ADT Problem

The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    ProductXmlManager.java  /SplashScreen/src/com/ust/mobile/android/jnj/mxr/xmlmanager line 1  Java Problem

The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project    SplashScreen        Unknown Java Problem
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like error of your development environment, not application. Check the settings if you changed something and check your build path.